How to render a screen only after all images have loaded in React Native?
I have a React Native app where I am rendering a set of buttons with images. The images are loaded individually, and I want to display the screen only after all 5 images have finished loading. Currently, the images are loading at different times, which causes a poor user experience as the UI appears incomplete before all images are loaded.
Problem:
The images for the buttons are loading at different times, which results in the screen being shown before all images are fully loaded. I would like to wait until all the images are loaded before displaying the buttons on the screen.
Expected Solution:
I want to render the screen only after all 5 images are loaded, so that the UI appears fully loaded when the user first sees it.
How can I implement this in React Native?
Here is the code I am using:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import styles from "./MainPageStyle";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Page1 from "./HomePage"; // 메인페이지
import Page2 from "./AlramPage"; // 알림함
import Page3 from "./HomePage"; // 상품정보
import Page4 from "./HomePage"; // 환경설정

// 정적 이미지 import
import homeBtnImage from "../../assets/img/main/homeBtn.webp";
import bellBtnImage from "../../assets/img/main/bellBtn.webp";
import iconImage from "../../assets/img/main/icon.webp";
import goodsBtnImage from "../../assets/img/main/goodsBtn.webp";
import settingBtnImage from "../../assets/img/main/settingBtn.webp";

// 버튼 데이터 배열
const buttonData = [
  { id: "page1", source: homeBtnImage, target: "page1" },
  { id: "page2", source: bellBtnImage, target: "page2" },
  {
    id: "barcode",
    source: iconImage,
    target: "BarcodeScanner",
    isNavigation: true,
  },
  { id: "page3", source: goodsBtnImage, target: "page3" },
  { id: "page4", source: settingBtnImage, target: "page4" },
];

// 버튼 컴포넌트
const IconButton = ({ source, onPress, isSelected, onLoad }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={[styles.btn, isSelected && styles.selectedBtn]}
    onPress={onPress}
  >
    <Image
      source={source}
      onLoad={onLoad}
      style={[styles.image, isSelected && styles.selectedImage]}
      resizeMode="contain"
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const MainPage = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState("page1");

  const renderPage = () => {
    switch (currentPage) {
      case "page1":
        return <Page1 />;
      case "page2":
        return <Page2 />;
      case "page3":
        return <Page3 />;
      case "page4":
        return <Page4 />;
      default:
        return <Page1 />;
    }
  };

  const handleButtonPress = (button) => {
    if (button.isNavigation) {
      navigation.navigate(button.target);
    } else {
      setCurrentPage(button.target);
    }
  };

  const handleImageLoad = (id) => {
    console.log("id", id);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* 현재 페이지 */}
      {/* {renderPage()} */}

      {/* 버튼 컨테이너 */}
      <View style={styles.btContainer}>
        {buttonData.map((button) => (
          <IconButton
            key={button.id}
            source={button.source}
            onLoad={() => handleImageLoad(button.id)} // 이미지 로드 이벤트
            isSelected={currentPage === button.target}
            onPress={() => handleButtonPress(button)}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MainPage;




add a state for image loaded count
on image load increment the image loaded count
only render the screen if image loaded count is equal to button images

const [imageLoadedCount, setImageLoadedCount] = useState(0)

const handleImageLoad = (id) => setImageLoadedCount(imageLoadedCount + 1);

...

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       {imageLoadedCount >= 4 && renderPage()}  // render screen when images loaded are up to button images 
...

try this and see if it resolves your issue, happy coding!
